# Java stream findany help required

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have an object that contains a Customer.name attribute.  I would like to iterate over a list of Customers to see if the name is not "Joe" or "Bob".

How can I use Java stream / find any to identify if any of the names are not "Joe" or "Bob"

```
 boolean nameCheck = customers.stream().anyMatch(!c -> c.getName().equals("Joe") ||  !c.getName().equals("Bob"))
```

Bascially, I want to find the best way to return a boolean telling me that all customers are named Joe or Bob. Help much appreciated!

Comment: `allMatch` instead of `anyMatch`?

Comment: first (and second) you want 'the name is **not** "Joe" or "Bob"' but at the end you ask for '**all** are named "Joe" or "Bob"' ??

Comment: Just as info, `noneMatch` also exists, updated my answer, but here `allMatch` still best as no `!` is requierd to confuse yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, here 3 of them using `Streams` :

1. Check that all are Bob or Joe with `allMatch` :

   ```
   boolean onlyBobJoe = customers.stream()
                  .allMatch(c -> c.getName().equals("Joe") || c.getName().equals("Bob"));
   ```
2. Check that none is neither Bob nor Joe with `anyMatch` (be careful`!` at beginning):

   ```
   boolean onlyBobJoe = !customers.stream()
                  .anyMatch(c ->!c.getName().equals("Joe") && !c.getName().equals("Bob"));
   ```
3. Check that none Is neither Bor nor Joe with `noneMatch`

   ```
   boolean onlyBobJoe = customers.stream()
                 .noneMatch(c ->!c.getName().equals("Joe") && !c.getName().equals("Bob"));
   ```

---

```
if(onlyBobJoe) System.out.println("Only Bob, Joe's customers");
else System.out.println("One has a different name !");
```

Comment: @DidierL dit i failed one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

try with `.allMatch(p-> p.getName().matches("Joe|Bob"))`

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Customer> customers =   new ArrayList<>(asList(new Customer("Joe"), new Customer("Bob")));

        customers.stream().map(Customer::getName).forEach(System.out::println);//print list
        Boolean allCustomersAreJoeOrBob =  customers.stream().allMatch(p-> p.getName().matches("Joe|Bob"));
        System.out.println("allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: "+allCustomersAreJoeOrBob+"\n");

        Customer sarasa = new Customer("Sarasa");
        customers.add(sarasa);
        customers.stream().map(Customer::getName).forEach(System.out::println);//print list
        allCustomersAreJoeOrBob =  customers.stream().allMatch(p-> p.getName().matches("Joe|Bob"));
        System.out.println("allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: "+allCustomersAreJoeOrBob+"\n");

        customers.remove(sarasa);
        customers.add(new Customer("Joe"));
        customers.stream().map(Customer::getName).forEach(System.out::println);//print list
        allCustomersAreJoeOrBob =  customers.stream().allMatch(p-> p.getName().matches("Joe|Bob"));
        System.out.println("allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: "+allCustomersAreJoeOrBob+"\n");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Joe
Bob
allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: true

Joe
Bob
Sarasa
allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: false

Joe
Bob
Joe
allCustomersAreJoeOrBob: true
```